# How do I do a chunked transfer-encoding upload with WWW:Mechanize?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize, lwp, chunked-encoding, chunked

I'm attempting to use a particular web service, and I can successfully perform the upload with the following command:

```
curl -X POST  --header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" -d @Downloads/file.pdf https://some.webservice/upload
```

I get back a json response indicate success.

However, I'm unable to figure out how to do the same with WWW::Mechanize.

```
$mech->post("https://" . $server . "/upload", Content_Type => 'multipart/form-data', Content => [upID => $upid, name => $dlfile, userID => 0, userK => 0, file_0 => [$dlfile]]);
```

This receives a similar json response with a big fat error message in it.

Do I need to explicitly set the Transfer-Encoding header first? Is there some other trick to it? Google's not shedding much light on this, Perlmonks neither, and the documentation's a little obtuse.

Comment: The reason chunked is only used when callback is used is because the content length is otherwise known in advance, and there's no point to using chunked encoding if the content length is known.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using HTTP::Request::StreamingUpload

```
my $starttime = time();
my $req = HTTP::Request::StreamingUpload->new(
    POST     => $url,
    path    => $file,
    headers => HTTP::Headers->new(
        'Transfer-Encoding' => 'chunked' 
    ),
);

my $gen = $req->content;
die unless ref($gen) eq "CODE";

my $total = 0;
$req->content(sub {
    my $chunk = &$gen();
    $total += length($chunk);

    print "\r$total / $size bytes ("
        . int($total/$size*100)
        . "%) sent, "
        . int($total/1000/(time()-$starttime+1))
        . " k / sec ";

    return $chunk;
});

my $resp = $ua->request($req);
print "\n";

unless ($resp->is_success) {
    die "Failed uploading the file: ", $resp->status_line;
}

my $con = $resp->content;
return $con;
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution seems to work correctly... json response has no errors now. I've still got a few things to figure out besides the (previous) error, but I think I can get the rest now.

Answer (score 4):

Do you really need `WWW::Mechanize`? It is a subclass of `LWP::UserAgent` with additional functionality that gives browser-like functionality like filling in and submitting forms, clicking links, a page history with a "back" operation etc. If you don't need all of that then you may as well use `LWP::UserAgent` directly

Either way, the `post` method is inherited unchanged from `LWP::UserAgent`, and it's fine to use it directly as you have done

The way to send a chunked `POST` is to set the `Content` to a reference to a subroutine. The subroutine must return the next chunk of data each time it is called, and finally ann empty string or `undef` when there is no more to send

Is the data supposed to be a JSON string?

It's easiest to write a factory subroutine that returns a closure, like this

```
sub make_callback {
    my ($data) = shift;
    sub { substr($data, 0, 512, "") }
}
```

Then you can call `post` like this

```
my $payload = to_json(...);

$mech->post(
    "https://$server/upload",
    Content_Type => 'multipart/form-data',
    Content      => make_callback($payload)
);
```

*Please be aware that all of this is untested*

Comment: I'm ok with using LWP directly, I just don't want to resort to system()ing the curl command, nor would I want to rewrite what's already a large script in python or something else. Thank for this, I'll get to tinkering with it. Trying to follow along with what I was seeing in dev tools, and I don't think I understood how this worked until you pointed it out.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with other fields besides the file contents? I can make the file upload, but it stumbles on several other missing values (as near as I can tell).